# How can I set the Master Page programmatically under MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

In plain ASP.NET this is an easy job... just override the `Page_PreInit` and done!

but how do I accomplish this under **ASP.NET MVC2** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's even easier in ASP.NET MVC, just pass in the master page's name as the second parameter:

```
return View("MyView", "MyMasterPage");
```

Of course, you can also create your own `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` and do the master page change in there.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do this in an override (in the controller or base controller) if you've got some actions that are shared between say an admin and user site:

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, 
                                   string masterName, object model)
{

    // we share some views that aren't partialviews
    // therefore, we have to ensure that the Shareholder master template
    // is ALWAYS attached to the logged in user if they aren't an admin user
    bool userIsAdmin = IsAuthorised("Admin");

    if (!userIsAdmin) // then flip the masterpage to Shareholder.Master
    {
        masterName = "Shareholder";
    }

    return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
}
```

another way to hang yourself, i mean, skin the cat :)